# TLS/SSL session resume on FTP transfer connection with OpenSSL

Tags: session, ssl, ftp, openssl, resume

I'm open source developer implementing FTP client ([WinSCP](https://winscp.net/)).

I'm trying to resume TLS/SSL session from the FTP control socket on the transfer socket.
Some FTP servers started to require this.

E.g. vsftpd:
https://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.com/2009/02/vsftpd-210-released.html

---

I'm using OpenSSL to implement SSL layer.

I've tried the obvious way to implement the session resume, i.e. to use `SSL_get1_session` and `SSL_set_session`, like here:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5487

Though it does not work. I'm still not able to connect to any FTP server requiring TLS session resume (like the vsftpd).

I have suspicion that the problem may be due to in my case, there are two parallel TLS connections, which cannot share the same TLS session. Which is different to the example on linuxjournal.com, where the first connection is closed before the other is opened.

I have also tried several ways to clone the session, e.g. using `i2d_SSL_SESSION`/`d2i_SSL_SESSION`. Didn't help either.

I'm really stuck here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `SSL_get1_session` and the `SSL_set_session` worked in the end. I must have used them incorrectly when trying the first time.

- Once the TLS/SSL session on the control connection is established, use [`SSL_get1_session`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_session.html) to retrieve the session.

  - I specifically do it from a callback set by the [`SSL_set_info_callback`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_info_callback.html), when `where & SSL_ST_CONNECT`.
  - But for TLS 1.3 (`SSL_version >= TLS1_3_VERSION`), I had to use [`SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode.html) with `SSL_SESS_CACHE_CLIENT | SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL_STORE | SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_AUTO_CLEAR`, and use a callback set by [`SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb.html).
- Call the [`SSL_set_session`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_set_session.html) with the reference to the control connection session, when setting up TLS/SSL session for the data connection.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I'm also developing an FTP client with OpenSSL and this whole thing caused me some head scratching.

Answer (score 2):

You must specifically enable client session caching on your `SSL_CTX` object with:

```
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_CLIENT);
```

You may also need to increase the default session cache timeout (the default is 300 seconds), using `SSL_CTX_set_timeout()`.

(You must also be creating your `SSL` objects from the same `SSL_CTX` object).